# Pandas DataFrame (long) to Series ("wide")

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

|  | completeness | homogeneity | label_f1_score | label_precision | label_recall | mean_bbox_iou | mean_iou | px_accuracy | px_f1_score | px_iou | px_precision | px_recall | t_eval | v_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mean | 0.1 | 1 | 0.92 | 0.92 | 0.92 | 0.729377 | 0.784934 | 0.843802 | 0.898138 | 0.774729 | 0.998674 | 0.832576 | 1.10854 | 0.1 |
| std | 0.0707107 | 0 | 0.0447214 | 0.0447214 | 0.0447214 | 0.0574177 | 0.0313196 | 0.0341158 | 0.0224574 | 0.0299977 | 0.000432499 | 0.0327758 | 0.0588322 | 0.0707107 |

What I would like to obtain is a Series composed of `completeness_mean`, `completeness_std`, `homogenety_mean`, `homogenety_std`, ..., i.e. a label `{column}_{index}` for every cell.

Does Pandas have a function for this or do I have to iterate over all cells myself to build the desired result?

EDIT: I mean a Series with `{column}_{index}` as index and the corresponding values from the table.

(I believe this is not a duplicate of the other questions on SO related wide to long.)

Comment: `stack` and flatten the MultiIndex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and flatten the index:

```
df2 = df.unstack()
df2.index = df2.index.map('_'.join)
```

output:

```
completeness_mean       0.100000
completeness_std        0.070711
homogeneity_mean        1.000000
homogeneity_std         0.000000
label_f1_score_mean     0.920000
label_f1_score_std      0.044721
label_precision_mean    0.920000
label_precision_std     0.044721
label_recall_mean       0.920000
label_recall_std        0.044721
mean_bbox_iou_mean      0.729377
mean_bbox_iou_std       0.057418
mean_iou_mean           0.784934
mean_iou_std            0.031320
px_accuracy_mean        0.843802
px_accuracy_std         0.034116
px_f1_score_mean        0.898138
px_f1_score_std         0.022457
px_iou_mean             0.774729
px_iou_std              0.029998
px_precision_mean       0.998674
px_precision_std        0.000432
px_recall_mean          0.832576
px_recall_std           0.032776
t_eval_mean             1.108540
t_eval_std              0.058832
v_score_mean            0.100000
v_score_std             0.070711
dtype: float64
```

or with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for a different order:

```
df2 = df.stack()
df2.index = df2.swaplevel().index.map('_'.join)
```

output:

```
completeness_mean       0.100000
homogeneity_mean        1.000000
label_f1_score_mean     0.920000
label_precision_mean    0.920000
label_recall_mean       0.920000
mean_bbox_iou_mean      0.729377
mean_iou_mean           0.784934
px_accuracy_mean        0.843802
px_f1_score_mean        0.898138
px_iou_mean             0.774729
px_precision_mean       0.998674
px_recall_mean          0.832576
t_eval_mean             1.108540
v_score_mean            0.100000
completeness_std        0.070711
homogeneity_std         0.000000
label_f1_score_std      0.044721
label_precision_std     0.044721
label_recall_std        0.044721
mean_bbox_iou_std       0.057418
mean_iou_std            0.031320
px_accuracy_std         0.034116
px_f1_score_std         0.022457
px_iou_std              0.029998
px_precision_std        0.000432
px_recall_std           0.032776
t_eval_std              0.058832
v_score_std             0.070711
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
pd.merge(df.columns.to_frame(), df.index.to_frame(), 'cross').apply('_'.join, axis=1)
# OR
pd.Series(df.unstack().index.map('_'.join))
```

Output:

```
0        completeness_mean
1         completeness_std
2         homogeneity_mean
3          homogeneity_std
4      label_f1_score_mean
5       label_f1_score_std
6     label_precision_mean
7      label_precision_std
8        label_recall_mean
9         label_recall_std
10      mean_bbox_iou_mean
11       mean_bbox_iou_std
12           mean_iou_mean
13            mean_iou_std
14        px_accuracy_mean
15         px_accuracy_std
16        px_f1_score_mean
17         px_f1_score_std
18             px_iou_mean
19              px_iou_std
20       px_precision_mean
21        px_precision_std
22          px_recall_mean
23           px_recall_std
24             t_eval_mean
25              t_eval_std
26            v_score_mean
27             v_score_std
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! No, I mean a Series with `{column}_{index}` as index and the corresponding values.

Comment: @moi so, what mozway has? Don't forget to accept their answer if so.